# Get a single element from array based on condition MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

## Schema

```js
// Doc
{
    _id:"sr_1",
    posts:[
        {
            _id:"1",
            title:"Post 1",
            tags:["rahul","kumar","thakur"]
        },
        {
            _id:"2",
            title:"Post 2",
            tags:["shani","kumar","sharma"]
        },
        ....
    ]
}
```

## What do i want?

I want to get `title` attribute of a `post`.

Where

- post id `2`
- post is inside `posts` array
- `posts` array is inside document with `_id` **sr_1**.

## My Solution

```js
Blog.find({
    _id: "sr_1",
    "posts._id": "2"
},
    { "posts.$": 1 }
)
    .then(docs => {
        docs.forEach(post => console.log(post))
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
```

This solution is working but when i replace `Blog.find` by `Blog.findById` or `Blog.findOne` then i am getting error:

```js
MongoError: positional operator '.$' couldn't find a matching element in the array
```

#### Can anyone tell me why i am getting error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `elemMatch` and try this:

```
Blog.find({_id: "sr_1"
    },  
   { posts: { $elemMatch: { _id: '2', title: 'Post 2' } } },
  { "posts.$": 1}
);
```

Comment: Hey, it's returning the entire post, insted i just want to get `title` of post

Comment: `I want to get title attribute of a post.`